# How to scroll 3 listviews in different fragment at the same time?

Tags: android

I have 3 ListViews in one layout but in 3 different fragments. I want, when i scroll down, to first load the first listview  and the other two listviews to scroll background at same the time when 1 change fragment same position
    display at 2nd and 3rd fragment i loaded listview from database. 
[Pic of 1st fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBwpE.png)

```
//first fragment code

public class Quran extends Fragment {

    ListView quranlst;
    Parcelable state;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_quran, container, false);
    }


    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        quranlst = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.quranlist);
        DatabaseAccess db = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        Intent it = getActivity().getIntent();




        int p = it.getIntExtra("paya", 0);
        int i = it.getIntExtra("saya", 0);

        if (i != 0) {


            List<String> lstsa;
            db.open();
            lstsa = db.getsaya(i);

            db.close();



            MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(lstsa, Quran.this.getActivity());



            quranlst.setAdapter(adapter);

        } else if (p != 0) {

            List<String> lstpa;
            db.open();
            lstpa = db.getpaya(p);
            db.close();



            MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(lstpa, Quran.this.getActivity());

            //handle listview and assign adapter

            quranlst.setAdapter(adapter);

        }


    }



}
```

[pic of Second fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O14kJ.png)
     **that is my 2nd fragment code**

```
public class englisht extends Fragment {

    ListView el;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_englisht, container, false);}




    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        el = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.englishlst);


        DatabaseAccess db = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        Intent it = getActivity().getIntent();




        int i = it.getIntExtra("saya", 0);
        int p = it.getIntExtra("paya", 0);

        if (i != 0) {
            List<String> lstenglishsurah;
            db.open();
            lstenglishsurah = db.geteaya(i);
            db.close();


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),  R.layout.mytextview, lstenglishsurah);
            el.setAdapter(adapter);


        } else if (p != 0) {

            List<String> lstenglishparah;
            db.open();
            lstenglishparah = db.paraheng(p);
            db.close();


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),  R.layout.mytextview, lstenglishparah);
            el.setAdapter(adapter);


        }
    }
}



**that is my third fragment code**
public class urdut extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Returning the layout file after inflating
        //Change R.layout.tab1 in you classes
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_urdut, container, false);}




    ListView urdulst;




    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


        urdulst = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.urdulst);


        DatabaseAccess db = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        Intent it = getActivity().getIntent();


        //SurahAyat

        int i = it.getIntExtra("saya", 0);
        int p = it.getIntExtra("paya", 0);

        if (i!=0) {
            List<String> lsturdusurah;
            db.open();
            lsturdusurah = db.getuaya(i);
            db.close();


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.mytextview, lsturdusurah);
            urdulst.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
        else if (p!=0) {


            List<String> lsturduparah;
            db.open();
            lsturduparah = db.parahurdu(p);
            db.close();


            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),  R.layout.mytextview, lsturduparah);
            urdulst.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you share screenshot of the design screen so we might suggest some better approach or it will help to understand the problem.

Comment: how i show design of app

Comment: I upload screenshot of app plz check it

Comment: you will display one fragment at a time ?

Comment: yes i want scroling at same time 3 fragment

Comment: becasue i want same translation when i chang fragment   of that text that use in ist fragment listview

Comment: do u have any idea what is better aproch for this

Answer (score 0):

**First get scroll position of the list view using this code**

View c = listview.getChildAt(0);
int no= -c.getTop() + listview.getFirstVisiblePosition() * c.getHeight();

**and then set listview scroll position to other fragment**

```
getListView().setSelection(no);
```

no is : like 1,2,3....

Comment: how to use getListview and no in other fragment it show an error

Comment: getlistview() means your listview name and no save as static variable

Comment: i set listview and no in static error in other fragmnt no resolv

Comment: cannot resolve symbol no  and conot resolve method getlistview

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods smoothScrollToPosition and smoothScrollToPositionFromTop to scroll list(other lists) with respect to first list to which you are scrolling

Comment: i use in first listview but how i use same scrolling in other fragmets